# Using the notion of provability only, how to show that $\Gamma \nvdash \varphi$?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, meta-math, metalogic

For a practical example, suppose I want to show that $\{ P\} \nvdash Q$. From completeness, this is trivial: just find a model where $P$ is true and $Q$ false.

But suppose I am stubborn and *I don't want to use completeness*. Is there still a way to prove it?

For this particular case, I guess one could find the *deductive closure* of $\{P\}$, and show that $Q \notin Ded(\{P\})$. But this is simple because we just have one premise. On the other hand, this procedure seems to get complicated in the a general case where we have a set of $n$ premises

$$\varphi_1, \varphi_2 ... \varphi_{n-1}, \varphi_n \nvdash \psi$$

How to proceed then? Then, *my question is*:

What are the standard ways to show, relying on the notion of provability alone, that
$$\Gamma \nvdash \varphi$$
For some $\Gamma$ and $\varphi$?

Comment: You have to prove that $\Gamma$ is *consistent* and that $\Gamma \vdash \lnot \varphi$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Could you elaborate it a little bit further?

Comment: If $\Gamma$ is consistent, then it does not prove a statement and its negation. If you prove that $\Gamma$ is consistent, and it proves $\lnot\varphi$, then you have proved that it does not prove $\varphi$ itself. In fact, it is sufficient to just show that $\Gamma\cup\{\lnot\varphi\}$ is consistent, which is a bit more general than what @Mauro suggested (and in fact $\Gamma$ does not prove $\varphi$ if and only if $\Gamma\cup\{\lnot\varphi\}$ is consistent). As for how to do it? It's probably not very easy, that's why mathematicians do it with models.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I see, thanks! As for Mauro's suggestion, it do not seem to apply for every case indeed. Just take my example above, $P \nvdash Q$. $P$ is consistent, but $P \vdash \neg Q$. About your guys suggestion though, allow me a (*possibly naive*) question: isn't it circular? showing that some set $\Gamma$ is consistent means showing that $\Gamma \nvdash \neg \varphi \land \varphi$. But asking how to prove that something does not follow syntatically from the premises is my own question..!

Comment: Small note: in order to say "since I have a model of $\Gamma$ which doesn't satisfy $\varphi$, therefore $\Gamma\not\vdash\varphi$, you're using **soundness** (which is less mathematically deep IMHO), not **completeless**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way to see that there is no really satisfactory, general answer. Recall that the deduction systems for first-order logic are computably effective. A theory $\Gamma$ is effective if we can computably enumerate its axioms. Because the deductive system is effective, if $\Gamma$ is an effective theory then we can also enumerate its deductive closure $\text{Ded}(\Gamma)$.

But there are many effective theories $\Gamma$ for which $\text{Ded}(\Gamma)$ is not decidable: there is no algorithm to determine, given a sentence $\phi$, whether $\Gamma \vdash \phi$.  One such theory is Peano arithmetic.

This means that there will be no general, effective way to determine, for an arbitrary theory $\Gamma$ and an arbitrary sentence $\phi$, whether $\Gamma$ proves $\phi$. The spirit of the question is looking for such a method, which presumably would use some kind of syntactic analysis to determine the sentences provable from $\Gamma$.

For certain particular theories, it is possible to decide whether arbitrary sentences are in the deductive closure. Such theories are called "decidable" in the literature. One example of such a theory is the theory of Boolean algebras. There is a list of theories in the Wikipedia article [List of first-order theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_first-order_theories), which has several examples of decidable and undecidable theories. Donald Monk's textbook on logic also has detailed coverage of some decidable and undecidable theories, and I recommend it as an entry point to this topic.

For the theories that are decidable, there are several methods used to establish decidability. Because there is no general method overall, a proof of decidability must necessarily depend on some particular aspects of the theory being studied. One often-used method is known as "quantifier elimination": it is shown that the theory $\Gamma$ proves each sentence $\phi$ is equivalent to some quantifier-free sentence $\phi^{qf}$, and then a syntactic analysis is performed to determine which quantifier-free sentences are provable from $\Gamma$. A particular example of this is Tarski's theorem showing that the theory of [real closed fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field) is decidable.

Comment: That's a great argument. I wonder how I didn't think of it, seeing how we just wrapped out the incompleteness theorem (and related topics) in our course.